# creating iOS style back button

Tags: css, jquery-mobile-button

I am trying to create a iOS style back button for my jQuery mobile based app here is what i have tried ..

### HTML

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.history.go(-1); return false;" class="ui-btn  ui-btn-icon-left ui-corner-all">Back</a>
```

### CSS

```
.ui-btn-left {
    background: linear-gradient(#9fbfe7, #6e84a0) repeat scroll 0 0 #87a2c4;
    border: #000000;
}
```

what i couldn't achieve is

- making text color white
- making triangle shaped button from left side

like this
[image]

here is the Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/A6u9n/

Comment: http://writings.orangegnome.com/writes/ios-style-back-button-in-css/

Answer (score 0):

Here is example of iOS Style “Back” Button in CSS. 
http://writings.orangegnome.com/writes/ios-style-back-button-in-css/